# Django Rest Framework Serializer Relations: How to get list of all child-child objects in parent's serializer?

Tags: django

I'm new to DRF and have just started building an API. I have three models, a child model connected to a parent model with a foreign key. Here is the simplified version of the model I have:

union models:

```
class Union(core_models.TimeStampedModel):

    # 공통
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  # 조합명
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owner"
    )  # 조합을 만든 계정
```

user models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)  # 닉네임
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)  # 비밀번호
    # 학력사항
    education = models.ManyToManyField(
        education_models.Education, related_name="education", blank=True
    )

    # 경력사항
    career = models.ManyToManyField(
        career_models.Career, related_name="career", blank=True
    )
```

career models:

```
class Career(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)  # 회사명
    job = models.CharField(choices=JOB_CHOICES, max_length=50)  # 직무
    status = models.BooleanField()  # 재직_상태 (재직상태면 True, 아니면 False)
```

in documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations), there is only parent-child case, but I create/update the career models in union serealizer.

I think it's perfectly reasonable, but I couldn't understand what I'm missing here.

How can I create/upate children-children in parent's serializer?

Comment: What do you call child-child relationship ? Can you provide an example of what you want with your models ?

Comment: I mean parent -> child -> child-child. I don't know how exactly call this relation... when I create union instance, I want to create/update owner(this is user model) and career which is relation with owner(user). could you understand?

Comment: You will have to pop the data relative to the child and **inside** this data, you will have another dictionnary object relative to the grand-child element... now what you want to do with it is up to you...